# How to Dynamically get All path's from props React Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

The App can't switch and render All the routes. It gets only one path (firstOne) and renders it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Board extends Component {
  state = {
    routes: []
  };

  showRoutes = routes =>
    routes.length > 0 &&
    routes.map((route, i) => (
      <Route key={i} path={route.path} component={()=>"path"+i} />
    ));

  render() {
    const { routes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => "start page"} />

          {this.showRoutes(routes.routesApi)}

          <Route path="/" render={() => "no such routes"} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  routes: state.routes
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Board);
```

I have also used `componentWillReceiveProps()` as:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(NextProps) {
    this.setState({ routes: NextProps.routes });
  }
```

and switch to read data from state, but the result is the same.

Could you help me please to understand what is wrong?

Comment: Can you use react devtools to make sure the routes are rendered correctly inside Switch ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is there. There is only one route (the first one) inside the Switch. But as in Component as in Switch(children) the props contain all path's

Comment: and you are sure that `this.props.routes.routesApi` has a value ?

Comment: Yes. It appear after second render (after getting the props)